# Direct connection and data fetching to mysql server using android

Tags: android, mysql, database

Is it possible to connect to a mysql database using android service and asynctask without using any server site scripts such as php??

My application needs to create an offline replica database, and synchronize if updated by user.

Please give suggestion and possible links, references or code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you aware of the problems of directly connecting your database without webservice ?

Comment: No, I am not. Would you please shortly describe this aspects?

Answer (score 0):

be aware of this :

if you connect to a remote DataBase without using a webService you will store the database login credentials inside your app. so it'll be easy to extract your login for that database and access and edit it even destroy it by decompiling your app.